# Group of elements coming up inline - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

The requirement is the label should be on top of the input element whereas the group of each label and input element  should be inline with one another.

I am able to achieve the same with the below piece of code when label text is a bit long. When the text of the label is short, the input element is appearing inline with the label.

Probably what I am doing is wrong. Please let me know a better way to handle it through bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

Code -

```
<form class="form" id="taxCalcDetail">
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1">A1</label>
        <input type="text" name="t1" class="form-control" id="t1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1">A2</label>
        <input type="text" name="t2" class="form-control" id="t2">  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1">A3</label>
        <input type="text" name="t3" class="form-control" id="t3">  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show me your current output

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCclR.jpg

Comment: you can use " display:inline-block; " css property to your lable tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using`d-flex` and `flex-column` classes. Tried on some Bootstrap 4 playgrounds, worked as you need it to work. 
You can read more about it [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/).

```
<form class="form" id="taxCalcDetail">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">A1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">A2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">A3</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 you can use `d-inline-block` class

```
  <form class="form" id="taxCalcDetail">
  <div class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1 d-inline-block">A1</label>
        <input type="text" name="t1" class="form-control" id="t1">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1 d-inline-block">A2</label>
        <input type="text" name="t2" class="form-control" id="t2">  
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-lg-3 pb-3">
        <label class="small pb-1 d-inline-block">A3</label>
        <input type="text" name="t3" class="form-control" id="t3">  
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Giving the same output. I don't see any change.

Comment: you try to clear browser cache first and reload your html page. After that let me know its working or not

Comment: with d-inline-block it becomes a stacked form. Its not inline anymore.